# MapBox SDK for React Native Installation shows Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, mapbox

I created a React Native project with Expo using `expo init MapTry`. I am currently trying to install MapBox library into it. For some reason I get an error at the first step after trying to install it. I followed this guide of installation: https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps#Installation but for some reason I am getting an error message when I try to run `npm install rnmapbox/maps#main --save` from the terminal. The error says the following:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I also tried to search for it in the official NPM site and found this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rnmapbox/maps . After running the following code: `npm i @rnmapbox/maps` which was written there, I get the same error message as written above. What should I do? How can I use MapBox library in React Native?

Comment: Getting same error have you found any proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to run this command in your terminal

```
with NPM

npm install @rnmapbox/maps --save

with YARN
yarn add @rnmapbox/maps
```

Comment: Nope getting the same error again...